# Component reuse between ASP.NET and C#.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, portability, reusability

This might seem like a ridiculous question since I'm quite inexperienced in .NET.

Is it possible to build components in C#, using .NET, which can be reused in ASP.NET. For example if one would like to port an application onto the web.

If possible, how portable are they? I.e. can GUI be reused in some extent? Is there an intermediate format to use as base or is it required to use C# components as binaries?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Thanks for your input! I'm quite familiar with the design aspects of this problem, i.e. how to model components for reuse. However you made me realize that the question really is about - To what extent is .NET reusable between ASP and Windows? Can one say that certain packages of .NET components are independent of environment and some are platform specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely - a .NET class can be used in any kind of .NET application. However, it kind of depends on what part of the application you're talking about.

Generally, Windows Forms user interfaces are NOT reusable as ASP.NET user interfaces, because the design constraints are so different (i.e. web browsers only support a small number of controls, often use flow (not grid) layout, etc. Similarly, the events are different (a web form button isn't the same as a windows form button, etc.).

What you can reuse easily, though, if you do things correctly, is the business logic. Design your classes so that they don't internally know anything about whether it's a windows form or a web form (or a console application, or web service, etc.). That is, the classes should be pure implementations of your business logic. Then you can use those classes in any context you want to.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is yes - simply separate out the code you want to share between the two views into a interface-independent class, preferably in a separate assembly, and include that assembly.

The long answer is more complicated - the ability to do this will vary between application and application. You'll be able to separate out less code for UI intensive applications that don't do much behind the scenes (such as, say, some sort of graphics game), than you will for a very simple UI application that does a lot behind the scenes (say, a UI that consists of a single button that then kicks off a complex data manipulation process).

In the end - .NET provides the ability for you to do this. Your actual ability to do this will be very dependent on your own design abilities and your particular requirements. There's a lot of writing available on this subject - I suggest starting by taking a look at Design Patterns (though the original book writes examples in C++, I believe that someone has done a book with examples in C#. I cannot, however, speak to the quality of it.)

Answer (score 1):

I've never done it before, but i guess you can place the common code on a separated class. UI will need to be duplicated as windows forms and asp.net have completely difference programming approaches.